# Replace failed RAID 1 Drive on Intel Platform

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, hard-drive, raid1, intel

Good afternoon, I have a Intel Server running Windows 2008 R2 Standard. It has a RMS25PB080 Raid controller card in with. It has two logical drives, a RAID 1 and a RAID 5. The one harddrive on the RAID 1 is failing but I have no idea how to replace it. Must it be exactly the same drive? Can it be same size but different RPM (Currently it has SEAGATE SAS 6Gb/s ST3300657SS at 15000rpm)?

I have read here: [Replacing a failed drive - RAID 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/654649/replacing-a-failed-drive-raid-1) and here: [One drive failed in my RAID 1+0 array, am I safe to replace it without losing data?](https://serverfault.com/questions/475708/one-drive-failed-in-my-raid-10-array-am-i-safe-to-replace-it-without-losing-da) as well as here [SSDs or 15k sas for server OS / application drive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366014/ssds-or-15k-sas-for-server-os-application-drive/366018#366018) but it is flying over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated as out supplier says that they can't get the ST3300657SS Drive anymore.

Thank you!

UPDATE 1.
Supplier came back to me with the following HDD http://www.seagate.com/em/en/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/hdd/enterprise-performance-15k-hdd/?sku=ST300MP0005
Would this drive work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the new hard drive arrived today and I am very very relieved to see that it worked. Although it is a 2.5" and the bay is a 3.5". Set the drive to offline in RAID Console, swapped it out with the new hdd and it is now rebuilding the array.

Here was the HDD that I got: http://www.seagate.com/em/en/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/hdd/enterprise-performance-15k-hdd/?sku=ST300MP0005

Hope this helps someone else in the future